# If a tick on Uniswap V3 is a fraction less than .5, is it rounded down to 0?

Tags: uniswap

I am looking at this function in a contract. The contract is something built on top of Uniswap V3 so it uses many concepts from uniswap V3 such as ticks. As I understand it, a tick can be negative and it can be a fraction less than one. But I have been trying to test this function using fractions (you know what a nightmare that is in solidity) and it just reverts.

So my question is, if I was working with a uniswap position that had a fractional tick (let's say .33), would solidity just round it down to 0 before even engaging with a function like this?

```
function addTickLower(uint256 self, int24 _tickLower) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            return self + (uint256(uint24(_tickLower)) << 232);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EVM does not support floating point numbers. If you want to track the price to a sub-tick precision, use `sqrtPriceX96` instead of ticks.

Solidity does not allow "conversion of a fractional rational number to an integer" ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#ternary-operator)), so your question about the rounding direction of 0.33 does not really have an answer, such a code simply will not compile.